# How to interpret results of a Clustering Heart Failure Dataset?

Tags: python, clustering, k-means

I am doing an analysis about this dataset: [click](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heart+failure+clinical+records)

In this dataset there are 13 features, 12 of input and 1 is the target variable, called "DEATH_EVENT". I tried to predict the survival of the patients in this dataset, using the features.
Hoewever, now I was trying to do a cluster analysis to see if the patients are grouped in clusters.
This is the code I have written.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
Features = ['ejection_fraction','serum_creatinine'] #the highest correlated features with death_event
X = heart_data[Features]

wcss = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)
plt.title('Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()
```

[image: Elbow]
From this graph I can observe that there are 2 clusters. Now

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
pred_y = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
plt.scatter(X["ejection_fraction"], X["serum_creatinine"])
plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1], s=300, c='red')
plt.show()
```

And I obtained this chart:
[image: Centroids]

Now, what can I say from this chart? I think that it is unuseful, right?
I used only the features ejection_fraction and serum_creatinine because these are the only I used for the prediction. Or I have to use all the variables except from DEATH_EVENT? In this way:

```
X = heart_data.iloc[:, :11]
```

But in this case I obtain this:
[image: All features]

I am not able to understand these charts, I think that I am doing something wrong, but what? Where are the clusters? How to interpret these results?

UPDATE: I am not able to use Umap_learn, my Mac can not install it, I received a lot of errors. However, I did something related to your advices.
Here there is all the code: https://pastebin.com/RdJb0ydu
The first 2 parts are the code that you have written here.
In the 3rd part I use kmeans(n_clusters=2) because from the silhouette I saw that the best was with 2 clusters. Then I did the prediction and concatenated the results to the original dataset and I printed out the column of DEATH_EVENT and the column with the results of clustering.
From this column, what can I say? How can I understand if the 0 of the prediction refers to the survived patients or to the died patients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use all the features and see how the separateness of my clusters behave according to some metric, for example, `silhouette score`

Additionally, it is very important to scale your data prior to clustering since kmeans is a distance-based algorithm.

```
heart_data = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00519/heart_failure_clinical_records_dataset.csv")

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

Features = heart_data.drop(["DEATH_EVENT"], axis = 1).columns

X = heart_data[Features]

sc = []
for i in range(2, 25):
    kmeans = Pipeline([("scaling",StandardScaler()),("clustering",KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0))]).fit(X)
    score = silhouette_score(X, kmeans["clustering"].labels_)
    sc.append(score)
plt.plot(range(2, 25), sc, marker = "o")
plt.title('Silhouette')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('Score')
plt.show()
```

You could also try different combinations of features so that score is maximum

For visualization purposes you can use a decomposition technique

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("seaborn-whitegrid")

pca = Pipeline([("scaling",StandardScaler()),("decompositioning",PCA(n_components = 2))]).fit(X)

X2D = pca.transform(X)

plt.scatter(X2D[:,0],X2D[:,1], c = kmeans["clustering"].labels_, cmap = "RdYlBu")
plt.colorbar();
```

Last but not least, I recommend to use a manifold projection such as [UMAP](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in your data, It might help on your task by generating "well-defined" clusters (might but not necessarily, nonetheless it is worthy to try)

Look, by using UMAP the results seems to improve:

code:

```
# pip install umap-learn

heart_data = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00519/heart_failure_clinical_records_dataset.csv")

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, DBSCAN
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
from umap import UMAP

Features = heart_data.drop(["DEATH_EVENT"], axis = 1).columns

X = heart_data[Features]

sc = []
for i in range(2, 25):
    kmeans = Pipeline([("scaling",StandardScaler()),("umap",UMAP()),("clustering",KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++',random_state=0))]).fit(X)
    score = silhouette_score(X, kmeans["clustering"].labels_)
    sc.append(score)
plt.plot(range(2, 25), sc, marker = "o")
plt.title('Silhouette')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('Score')
plt.show()

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("seaborn-whitegrid")

kmeans = Pipeline([("scaling",StandardScaler()),("umap",UMAP()),("clustering",KMeans(n_clusters=3, init='k-means++',random_state=0))]).fit(X)

pca = Pipeline([("scaling",StandardScaler()),("umap",UMAP()),("decompositioning",PCA(n_components = 2))]).fit(X)

X2D = pca.transform(X)

plt.scatter(X2D[:,0],X2D[:,1], c = kmeans["clustering"].labels_, cmap = "RdYlBu")
plt.colorbar();
```

[image]

> Plot show first and second principal components of umap projection (It is simply a projection of how  all the features would look in 2D space)

> Colours are the cluster id. i.e. for every colour we see in which cluster the algorithm (k-means) assigned each observation to.

Comment: I tried the code that you wrote, but for the first block of code I received this error: AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'markers' and for the second one AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'camp' @Julio Jesus

Comment: sorry, the correct property is marker not markers

Comment: Fixed! I have made the changes necessary for reproducibility

Comment: So, from the first picture, I can say that the best configuration is with 2 clusters, because there is the highest score, right? And from the second picture what can I say? Til now I have not understand if I can say that my patients are divided in 2 clusters, survived and not survived. ;(  @Julio Jesus

Comment: Well, making statements about your clusters require more time and analysis in-depth, but I would go with 2 or 3 clusters and analyze if one cluster (hopefully) contains only or most of either negative or positive cases

Comment: Another experiment you could do is: Train a supervised model with this characteristics, have a good performance on classification on this data set and has a feature importance property (linear or tree-based model) and take only the n most important features for the classification model for clustering purposes, this might be a way to select features for your clustering algorithm

Comment: First of all, i will try tomorrow the code of umap, because i received errors during the installation on my mac. Replying to your first comment: what do you mean with go with 2 or 3 cluster an analyze... I mean, are there other steps after the code that you wrote? Replying to your second comment: I have already did as I said in the original post. I trained several models and I found that the best features are ejection_fraction and serum_creatinine, these are the most correlated features with DEATH_EVENT

Comment: Once you run your clustering algorithm you will obtain labels that will indicate what cluster each observation belongs to, so if X is your original matrix, you will simply create a new column named "cluster_id" that will be X["cluster_id"] = kmeans.predict(X) if you chose k = 2 you will have 2 possible values and so on... then you already have another column that is the original target value. What if you check if there is a relationship between the target and the clusterid, say for example "cluster 1 has 96% of positives cases" if so you are separating via clustering your data death/not death

Comment: Ok thank you. Tomorrow morning I will try and I will reply with the future errors, because I know that there will  be errors :D Thanks

Comment: Just be aware that when `kmeans.predict(X)` do not include the target column (only the features you trained your model on) and you will be ok

Comment: I edited the original post with the new stuff I did @Julio Jesus

Comment: I see you already have the cluster id and the target value, my idea is to construct a confusion matrix with these two columns and check if one of the clusters contains majority of deaths or not deaths cases. If so I would perform cluster profiling and check what characterizes the elements on each cluster and therefore the deaths vs none deaths. (This is not a recipe it is part of the analysis I would do but of course you should have your own ideas based on the hypothesis you establish at the beginning of your experiment I mean, there might be a reason behind clustering in the first place

Comment: Hello. I am already satisfied with the analysis I have done. I think I will try with your suggestion of the confusion matrix. Cluster profiling I have no idea of what is it, we did not do in our course. Thank you again for your answers. I have the last question for you: can you comment briefly the image that is the output of the piece of code related to PCA? I mean, what is represented in y and x axis? What are all that colours? I know PCA, but I did not understand the output of this part of code. @Julio Jesus

Comment: Sorry, other question: I understand your idea of the confusion matrix, but how can i understand If the predicted values by clustering, the 0 and the 1, correspond to original values. In the sense that, in the dataset for DEATH_EVENT, 1 means death, 0 survived. In my clusters what is 1 and what is 0? It is possible that the values are reversed, right?

Comment: Yes, the numbers returned by kmeans are simply identifiers for the cluster each observation belongs to (independently of the value of the target value)

Comment: Ok right, I was confused by these numbers :D I don't know if you have read my previous comment about PCA. If you can help me, thank you very much @Julio Jesus

Comment: Ah ok sorry, I noted only now that you edited the previous post. Thank you!!